# What are the reasons NOT to upgrade from a normal Google account to a Google Plus profile?

Tags: google-plus

I have a Google account that does not yet have a Google Plus profile.  I remember there being some reason why people didn't want to use Google Plus, but without upgrading to Google Plus I also can't use a lot of features such as reviewing Android apps, commenting on YouTube videos, etc.

I think one issue was that all your Picasa albums would be made public.  Is this still true?  Are there any other reasons not to upgrade to a Google Plus profile?

Comment: _I think one issue was that all your Picasa albums would be made public._ eh, no.

Comment: @Sathya when I originally started the process to upgrade to Google+ several years ago, I canceled when I got to a warning about my Picasa photo albums. I don't remember the exact message. It's possible I misinterpreted it, but the language at the time seemed to indicate that my albums would effectively be made public.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest reason is that you fall under the stricter Google+ naming policy.

As far as I know, the Picasa album permissions weren't ever changed.

Answer (score 0):

The ease of making something public to your following is just that much easier. Besides then you'd have to sort out what groups everyone goes in.